# How do I get my Eclipse shortcuts working again in Helios?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse-3.6

Since upgrading to Helios, some of my main shortcuts have stopped working; I use <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> for Subversion commit, but since the upgrade, hitting this combination in the navigator view behaves the same as just hitting <kbd>C</kbd> (moves to the next element that starts with C).

I've tried a few variations, but either get the same behaviour, or nothing happens at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: funny that there is an "Export CSV" button, but no import.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was able to fix it by going to `Window` -> `Customize Perspective` -> `Command Groups Availability` and ticking the `SVN` checkbox in `Available command groups`. This added a `SVN` menu and the shortcuts started working immediately.

Source of workaround: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=306173#c16

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Preferences > General > Keys`, 'commit', to see if the subclipse commit is there.
It is possible that the Subversion plugin stopped working in this edition (see also '`Help > About > Installation Details > Plug-ins`')

This is why I always avoid upgrading an existing Eclipse installation.
I will rather unzip a new Eclipse distribution elsewhere, and make it reference the same workspace than my previous Eclipse, and reinstall plugins.
That way, if some incompatibilities are detected, I still have a (previous) working installation *still* all set.

Comment: The commit command shows up as expected in the Keys preferences, and the keyboard shortcut appears next to the `Team -> Commit` command from the right click menu (and running commit from the right click menu works, so the plugin isn't completely broken).

I do still have the old eclipse installation, and the 'commit' key setups look identical (there are two other commit based commands, but both are in the CVS category with no binding - this is for both Helios and 3.5 (which still works fine))

Comment: @Cebjyre: I suppose the commit shortcut is not displayed as "overriding another command" (or being overridden by another command)?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem but my issue was that my keyboard had a "Function Lock" key, which set the Function keys to either work as Function keys or keyboard short cuts such as "Send" "Undo" "Open".  So at some point I must have accidentally hit the button and set it to the shortcut setting. I hit that again and it started working perfectly.